# Is there an equivalent to C++'s std::vector in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

Is there a lightweight replacement for PHP's `array` to be used when I don't need any of the associated array functionality? From what I know, `array` is a hash map internally, which is excessive and inefficient for storing a simple array of elements. If PHP had a class or programming construct similar to C++'s `std::vector`, it would be just great.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php): **[PHP arrays are] optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more.**  What are you trying to do, specifically, where arrays are causing you trouble?

Comment: Specifically, a PHP "array" is implemented as simultaneously a hashtable and a doubly-linked list. While this does mean insertion and removal operations carry a small extra overhead to maintain the various pointers, retrieval of all kinds is pretty heavily optimised.

Comment: @IMSoP So not only PHP's native arrays are inefficient in terms of time but also in terms of memory?

Comment: @DesmondHume I was trying to argue the opposite actually. Bear in mind that PHP is a **high-level** language: even a single integer is implemented as a relatively complex structure to manage copy-on-write, type-juggling, memory management, etc. If you're looking for tight memory structures, use a lower level language.

Comment: @IMSoP I wish I could, but where else would I find an assortment of useful functions and libraries as wide as in PHP.

Comment: It really sounds a bit like premature optimization though. Or is there a concrete case that you are facing in your project where the native arrays pose a problem?

Comment: @Gordon I haven't even started working on the project, so Donald Knuth's famous quote doesn't really apply here. It's beyond evil I guess :D

Comment: @DesmondHume Then you need to either stop thinking about details like structure efficiency, or scrap any plan to work in PHP, otherwise you'll be fighting yourself all the way. PHP is a convenient language to work with *because* of things like its array type, not *despite* them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at SPL datastructures. An example is http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php which is faster than normal array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

Comment: SPLFixedArray is faster than standard PHP arrays for random access; fractionally slower for sequential access (e.g. foreach()); but gives big memory savings. Conversely, SPLDoublyLinkedLists are faster than standard PHP arrays for sequential access - and it's good to see SPL datastructures being recommended

Comment: SplFixedArray is fixed though. [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is not.

Comment: @Gordon yes you're right. SplFixedArray was only an example and since OP doesn't told the specific use case it's hard to tell if it suits the need.

Comment: It might be still possible to implement behavior similar to `std::vector` with `SplFixedArray` class using its `setSize` method http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfixedarray.setsize.php

Answer (score 3):

No, PHP does not have a strict equivalent to `std::vector`.

We just use our [multi-purpose arrays](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) or one of the [additional datastructures in SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php), namely `SplFixedArray`, `ArrayObject` and some [Heaps](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php) and [Stacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splstack.php), but none of them are actually equivalent.

The closest thing I can think of to save memory is a [PECL extension for Judy Arrays](http://pecl.php.net/package/Judy):

> PHP Judy implements sparse dynamic arrays (aka Judy Arrays). This extension is based on the Judy C library. A Judy array consumes memory only when it is populated, yet can grow to take advantage of all available memory if desired. Judy's key benefits are scalability, high performance, and memory efficiency.

It supports the following modes:

- `BITSET` - Define the Judy Array as a Bitset with keys as Integer and Values as a Boolean
- `INT_TO_INT` - Define the Judy Array with key/values as Integer, and Integer only.
- `INT_TO_MIXED` - Define the Judy Array with keys as Integer and Values of any type.
- `STRING_TO_INT` - Define the Judy Array with keys as a String and Values as Integer, and Integer only.
- `STRING_TO_MIXED` - Define the Judy Array with keys as a String and Values of any type.

You likely want `INT_TO_MIXED`. Like I said, it's the closest I can think of. It's not the same. I've never used it before, so I can't tell if it meets your requirements in terms of efficiency.

You can browse the sourcecode at http://lxr.php.net/xref/PECL/Judy/